# VM Exception in solidity

Tags: exception, solidity, smartcontracts

I am using testrpc and truffle to test my smart contract before deploying it to the real network.

In my contract, each node has to register in the contract by calling the function register, after that he can send or receive messages to/from contract( the blockchain )

The problem is, when an address ( let say account 1 from testrpc accounts) call the functions (send or receive ) the transaction doesn't occur and this message appears

```
VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid JUMP at
```

But when I use another unregistered account to call this function, it works.

Although no messages have been sent or received but no exceptions..

Any idea how I can solve this.

Thanks

Comment: This might be a too late to ask but have you tried running your contracts in `remix ide`. Link: www.remix.ethereum.org.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your using an old version of solc to compile your solidity the chance of this being an optimization problem is almost none.

Now, what does this mean then, it can happen when for example you run a modifier and it doesn't work. or if you try to call a function you are not allowed to and it throws. For example, it happens a lot after an ICO finishes and you try to use a function that can't be used anymore due to a date constraint it returns an `Invalid Jump`

I can't see your code but I think you might have reversed your if condition in your modifier and now it returns true if the user is not registered.